# Django : View returns JSON content_dictionary, how to decode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, json, simplejson

Let me explain what I'm trying to do, and if someone could point the correct way to do it & a solution to where I'm stuck that would be great !

## Someone types url

`www.ABC.com/showItem/Blackberry`

I lookup "Blackberry" in my database and find data for it, now I want to show its details one a page.

## Hence in the View I do this

`return_data=simplejson.dumps(response_dict)`

`return render_to_response('workmodule/show_item_details.html', {"item_complete_data": return_data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

## In myHTML I do this

`data_from_django = {{ farm_complete_data }}`

`Question 1` : Is this the correct method to access the JSON data in the HTML ? Somehow I think there should be a better/cleaner way.

`Question 2` : Another problem is all quotes are replaced with `"&quot;"` hence the javscript breaks. If above is the correct way, how to I "decode" the string correctly.

`Note :` I have used jquery's `.ajax` function earlier and it works great if you are on a page already and making a call to backend. The views in that case have returned the data in the same fashion as above & the data wasn't escaped. Or so it seemed by the time my ajax success: or error: functions handled it.

Thanks for taking time to look at this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question 1: that's about right, actually.

Question 2: Don't decode it, pipe it to safe: {{farm_complete_data|safe}} so it doesn't try to html-escape it for you.

Comment: Thanks Yoni ! That worked. This is good since I'm loading from db. What if it was unsafe ? Just asking.

Comment: This poses a security threat. Try it with any JSON containing `</script>`, for instance. The fix is to use `JSONEncoderForHTML` when `dumps`-ing, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7801710/66226).

Comment: Trevor's right, at least if you allow arbitrary user-entered strings in the data you're passing back into the JSON - but when I originally posted this answer in early 2010, SimpleJSON hadn't yet added the JSONEncoderForHTML class :) (it was new in SimpleJSON 2.1, released a few months afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Why pass it to a template at all? You just want the JSON, so in the view, do this:

```
return simplejson.dumps(response_dict)
```

Then there's no need to worry about encoding/quoting.

Comment: Well, this is just data. I need to format it and show it, hence need to assign it to a javscript variable.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you're doing the formatting in a Django template, why convert it to JSON at all? But if you're sending it via an Ajax call, the Javascript will be doing the formatting and displaying.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly. This load of data that the view sends back is a whole lot of information. Its a pretty complex object. I haven't used dJangos templating system but in either case, this complex object will be used a number of times in the page lifecycle. It can be edited, the changes can be discarded to the original or ultimately saved. Its not a simple rendering. I will look at django templates as well, to see if this can be done in another way. Please let me know if you think my approach is incorrect. Thanks, I really appreciate your eyes on this.